# Is there an other way to define the "image" property

Tags: reactjs

I have just started learning React, and just have some knowledge about the components and functions in react. When moving forward in learning react I happened to develop a single page application.
For which I was developing a render function method, and then I happen to have an encounter with this error.

**Error Message**

TypeError: Cannot read property 'image' of undefined

[Error encountered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXBbl.png)

**Things I tried**
I tried changing the type of parameter that I was passing in my function RenderCard, instead of items to props. But it was also not working.

**Code**

Here is my Rendercard method

```
function RenderCard({item}){
    return(
        <Card>
            <CardImg src={item.image} alt={item.name}/>
            <CardBody>
                <CardTitle> {item.name}</CardTitle>
                {item.designation ? <CardSubtitle>{item.designation}</CardSubtitle>
                   :null}
                <CardText>{item.description}</CardText>   
            </CardBody>
        </Card>
    );
}
```

**Function being used**

```
function Home(props){
    return (
         <div className="container">
            <div className="row align-items-start">
                <div className="col-12 col-md m-1">
                    <RenderCard item={props.dish} />
                </div>
                <div className="col-12 col-md m-1">
                    <RenderCard item={props.promotion} />
                </div>
                <div className="col-12 col-md-1">
                    <RenderCard item={props.leader} />
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
    );
}
```

**Part of my JSON format file**

```
export const DISHES =
[
    {
    id: 0,
    name:'Uthappizza',
    image: '/public/assets/images/uthappizza.png',
    category: 'mains',
    label:'Hot',
    price:'4.99',
    featured: true,
    description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.'                    
    },
    {
    id: 1,
    name:'Zucchipakoda',
    image: '/public/assets/images/zucchipakoda.png',
    category: 'appetizer',
    label:'',
    price:'1.99',
    featured: false,
    description:'Deep fried Zucchini coated with mildly spiced Chickpea flour batter accompanied with a sweet-tangy tamarind sauce'
    },
```

Comment: Can you expand your code example, the error you have says item is undefined in your function.   Can you show how you call this RenderCard method.

Comment: Your code does not show where props.dish, props.promotion & props.leader come from nor their format, but in order to work in your RenderCard component they should look something like this: `{
  name: 'the alt of the image',
  image: 'the://url.of.the.img',
  designation: 'a subtitle of the image',
  description: 'a description of the image'
}`. Do you have something like this in your Home component props ?

Comment: they are coming from shared directory, where I have stored the data for indivual ,promotions , leaders, dishes in js file , and in JSON format

Comment: And you are sure your Home component have them ?

Comment: I am pretty sure , that the Home comp is using it

Comment: Can you add the part of the code where do you import the DISHES array and you pass it to the Home component ?